# Strange error with \mathbb in \xdef

Tags: errors

Developing a complex piece of code, I got the following cryptic error:

```
./error@test.tex:5: Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                    #4  \errhelp \@err@     ...
l.5 ...w@thmref@thm:defi:DistRn\endcsname{$\mathbb
                                                  {R}$}
```

By "binary search", I realized it was due to the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}
\expandafter\xdef\csname mw@thmref@thm:defi:DistRn\endcsname{$\mathbb{R}$}
\end{document}
```

and that turning `\xdef` into `\gdef` made it disappear. So I got curious and came here to ask: what is going on here and what does that error mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a reason `\xdef` isn't a supported command in latex, most tex constructs blow up in an edef. use  `\protected@edef` and then use `\protect` for any fragile commands.

if you go

```
\edef\foo{\def\zzz{hello}}
```

then it tries to expand (only) the tokens while defining `\foo`. `\def` isn't expandable so is just left as is, then it tries to expand `\zzz` and then typically gives an undefined command error (or if `\zzz` already has a definition you get an arbitrary error from expanding that definition). This is the whole reason for the latex `\protect` mechanism, and using `\xdef` directly just blows a hole right through it.

The reason the log output looks a bit odd is that it is revealing (or trying to reveal) an internal token with the interesting name

```
 \@err@                                                                 %
```

that is a token with 65 or so spaces in its name,

Comment: "then it tries to expand `\foo`"… isn't it expanding the tokens in the braces of the `\edef\foo`? So shouldn't it try to expand `\zzz` rather than `\foo` which it is defining?

Comment: @MickG, sorry that's what I meant, corrected;-)

Comment: Precisely 65, in fact. But that token is defined _inside_ `\GenericError`, so why do I see both? Shouldn't I be seeing merely one expansion level, or anyway many but in a logical order? I mean, `\GenericError` is between `\@err@                                                                 ` and `\mathbb` etc in "production order" (I mean, first there is `\mathbb`, then we get `\GenericError` which expands to define that token), but is not in the output. The way it was, the error actually got me thinking `\GenericError` was the undefined sequence :), which was obviously absurd.

Comment: normally tex shows some of the expansion context in error messages (even if \errorcontextlines is negative) so we use the `\@err@                                                       ` token specifically as it caused the error context lines to disappear. If an edef has caused things to expand in the wrong order, you (or I) could trace exactly what is happening but honestly it's rarely worth it, the error message for using fragile commands in an `\edef` should be just taken as an indication something has gone wrong, exactly what happens and what error is generated is just random artifacts